# Congruence of angles between two planes

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

Let $P$ and $Q$ denote planes in 3 dimensional Euclidean space whose intersection is a line $L$. Let $A, A', B, B'$ be points on $L$ such that $A\neq B$ and $A'\neq B'$. Let $C$ be a point on $P$ that is not on $L$, and let $D$ be a point on $Q$ that is not on $L$. Define $C'$ to be the unique point on $P$ on the same side of $L$ as $C$, such that $\angle B'A'C'$ is congruent to $\angle BAC$, and define $D'$ to be the unique point on $Q$ on the same side of $L$ as $D$ such that $\angle B'A'D'$ is congruent to $\angle BAD$. Are the angles $\angle CAD$ and $\angle C'A'D'$ congruent? If so, how can it be proved?

[image: An illustration of the problem]

Comment: Mark E on line AC such that EB is perpendicular to AB. Mark F on line AD such that FB is perpendicular to EB. Mark E', F' in the same way. Triangles EAB and E'A'B' are similar by angles. FAB and F'A'B' are similar by angles. Triangles EBF and E'B'F' are similar by angle EBF and sides. Triangles EAF and E'A'F' are similar by sides. Then angles EAF and E'A'F' are congruent.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I don't understand the construction. If $EB$ is perpendicular to $AB$, as you specified, and if $FB$ is perpendicular to $EB$, as you specified, then, unless the planes $P$ and $Q$ are perpendicular to each other (a fact which there is no reason to assume), $F$ must equal $A$.

Comment: F can't be equal A because FB is perpendicular to EB, and AB is clearly not perpendicular to AB. Note: Proposed construction can work only if both angles BAD and BAC are not 90°. If one of them or both are equal to 90°, then one of points E and F or both will not exist.

Comment: Approximate view of construction: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly7KI.png

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Is it possible that you meant to write in your original comment that $FB$ is perpendicular to $AB$ (rather than that $FB$ is perpendicular to $EB$, as you wrote)?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu With the correction suggested in my last comment, I now understand your construction, and see why it solves my question. Thanks.

Comment: OK. I've miswritten EB instead of AB.